# Dependency injection in a factory instantiated component

Tags: java, dependency-injection, seam, factory, seam2

There are two classes, `Foo` and `Bar`, implementing some interface `Baz` in my `Seam 2.2.2` powered application. I'm trying to establish a component of `Baz` type conditionally implemented with one of these two classes. For this purpose I've created a factory component, `BazFactory`, instantiating `Baz` with `Foo` or `Bar` depending on a value of `implClassName` field:

```
public interface Baz {...}

public class Foo implements Baz {

    @In
    String injectedValue1;

    ...
}

public class Bar implements Baz {

    @In
    String injectedValue2;

    ...
}

@Name("bazFactory")
@Scope(value = ScopeType.SESSION)
public class BazFactory {

    private String implClassName;

    public void setImplClassName(String implClassName) {
        this.implClassName = implClassName;
    }

    @Factory(value="baz", scope = ScopeType.SESSION)
    public Baz getBazImpl() throws Exception {
        Class.forName(this.implClassName).newInstance();
    }
}
```

The problem is that dependencies aren't injected into instantiated class in this case. The only workaround I've devised is to declare `Foo` and `Bar` as components:

```
@Name("foo")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class Foo implements Baz {

    @In
    String injectedValue1;

    ...
}

@Name("bar")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class Bar implements Baz {

    @In
    String injectedValue2;

    ...
}

@Name("bazFactory")
@Scope(value = ScopeType.SESSION)
public class BazFactory {

    private String implComponentName;

    public void setImplComponentName(String implComponentName) {
        this.implComponentName = implComponentName;
    }

    @Factory(value="baz", scope = ScopeType.SESSION)
    public Baz getBazImpl() {
        return (Baz) Component.getInstance(this.implComponentName);
    }
}
```

However, in this case there is a mess with scope types. For example, how would be scoped a component having `@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)` in it's declaration and `scope = ScopeType.SESSION` in declaration of a factory method instantiating this component (like in the example above)? Furthermore, the workaround involves creating one more component for each `Baz` implementation. Therefore this workaround looks ugly for me. I'd prefer to use the first way, if there were a solution to the dependency injection problem described above.

Is there a way to inject dependencies into a factory instantiated component?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing in much simpler way.
In your factory you should not use Class.forName().newInstance() for creation of a new instance.

On the other hand in your context file you can have beans like

```
<bean id="bar" class="com.techidiocy.Bar"/>
<bean id="foo" class="com.techidiocy.Foo"/>
```

**Assumption:** required properties for Bar and Foo will be autowired or injected manually.

In your factory you can load this contextfile using  and get the bean from it , by passing the bean name, as you are already getting this in your factory.

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
        ("classpath:context.xml");

 return context.getBean(implClassName);//implClassName is the input that you are receiving in factory
```

In this way you can return the desired implementation type depends on the input you receive in factory class.

Thanks

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this solution is meant for Spring Framework. My question is referred to Seam Framework 2.2.2, not Spring.

Comment: oh  sorry my bad it is meant for spring only, i completely lost it.
I will delete my answer. - Thanks for pointing it out.